# Qt: How to set the maximum width of a QVBoxlayout

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a horziontal layout that has two vertical layouts in it. `Vlayout1` and `VLayout2`. Now I want to set a maximum width limit of `VLayout1` so that if the form is expanded after that, only `Vlayout1` expands.
Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 14):

You can do a "hack" and place your layout inside a widget, for which you can define a maximum width:

```
QWidget *controlsRestrictorWidget = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout *layoutVControls = new QVBoxLayout();
controlsRestrictorWidget->setLayout(layoutVControls);
controlsRestrictorWidget->setMaximumWidth(350);
```

It works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the maximum size of a `QVBoxLayout`. You'll probably need to set the maximum size on the widgets the layout contains. If you want one of the layout to stretch while the other one stays the same size you can try the following in your mainwindow constructor:

```
   QPushButton* btn1 = new QPushButton("Button1");
   QPushButton* btn2 = new QPushButton("Button2");
   QHBoxLayout* hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
   QVBoxLayout* vLayout1 = new QVBoxLayout;
   QVBoxLayout* vLayout2 = new QVBoxLayout;

   hLayout->addLayout(vLayout1, 1);
   hLayout->addLayout(vLayout2, 0);
   vLayout1->addWidget(btn1);
   vLayout2->addWidget(btn2);

   QWidget* placeholder = new QWidget;
   placeholder->setLayout(hLayout);
   setCentralWidget(placeholder);
```

If you resize the window now, you'll see the layout that contains `Button2` stretching whereas the layout containing `Button1` stays the same size.